# I want to add a label to the title tag. Example, Page Title + Label Name

Tags: html, web, blogger, blogs

I'm using Blogger. I want to add a label to the Title section.  Example, Page Title + Label Name. It should change according to the labels in the articles.

Page Title(article) + Page Label Name

Example : `<title> <page-title> - <page-label-name> </title>`

Here's what I have tried:

```
<title>
<data:blog.pageName/> - <data:blog.searchLabel/> News
</title>
```

Comment: *I tried very hard but I couldn't.* Show us what you've tried..

Comment: <title><data:blog.pageName/> - <data:blog.searchLabel/> News</title>

Comment: you can't do it inside post (article)